# grails application continuously reloading automatically after run-app completes

Tags: grails, runtime-error

we have did some package path changes to our application. Since we did that and removed all the compilation errors and trying to do run-app, the application completes run-app and then again does a reloading.

basically it reloads the spring ui, spring security core and spring security acl plugins again and again continuously..
The error log doesnot show anything (it shows "failed to create some referential constraints"..which were always failing... not the real cause probably)
Application compiles successfully 
Hers the samle dump from the console

```
[native2ascii] Converting 1 file from C:\Users\pd\.grails\1.3.7\projects\gra\plugins\spy-0.2\grails-app\i18n to C:\U
sers\pd\.grails\1.3.7\projects\gra\resources\plugins\spy-0.2\grails-app\i18n

[native2ascii] Converting 1 file from C:\Users\pd\.grails\1.3.7\projects\gra\plugins\spring-mobile-0.3\grails-app\i1
8n to C:\Users\pd\.grails\1.3.7\projects\gra\resources\plugins\spring-mobile-0.3\grails-app\i18n
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\pd\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gratrunk\gra\target\classes
     [copy] Copied 2 empty directories to 2 empty directories under C:\Users\pd\.grails\1.3.7\projects\gra\resources

     [copy] Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under C:\Users\pd\.grails\1.3.7\projects\gra\resources
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\pd\.grails\1.3.7\projects\gra\tomcat
Running Grails application..

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Configuring Spring Security UI ...
Configuring Spring Security ACL ...
Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/gra
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\pd\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gratrunk\gra\target\classes
  [groovyc] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\pd\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gratrunk\gra\target\classes
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\pd\.grails\1.3.7\projects\gra\tomcat
Running Grails application..

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Configuring Spring Security UI ...
Configuring Spring Security ACL ...
Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/gra
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\pd\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gratrunk\gra\target\classes
  [groovyc] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\pd\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gratrunk\gra\target\classes
Application context shutting down...
Application context shutdown.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\pd\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gratrunk\gra>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have any source file with `last modified` date in future (sometimes happens when you have distributed team)

Answer (score 0):

There was a codec class in grails util which didnt have a package specifier and was getting compiled repeatedly in target, checked the target folder and saw many entries for codec.class.
The issue went away after I added the package name to the class.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

My problem with this issue was a different name of a file and its class name.

```
RunSteps.groovy

class RunStep { }
```